# How to provide localization and multilanguage text into app using Backend server webservies which contains translations like en.json and da.json?

Tags: react-native

I want to add multilanguage support for the application but all the keywords come from the backend Webservices. How to fetch that keyword and add translation in app?

I am using static keywords right at the moment, like in this code:

I have used react-native-i18n as a localization.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const en = {
    login: 'LOGIN',
    logout: 'LOGOUT',
    usernameInput: 'USERNAME',
    passwordInput: 'PASSWORD',
    dashboardDrawer: 'Dashboard',
    historyDrawer: 'History',
    feedbackDrawer: 'Feed back',
    settingsDrawer: 'Settings',
    helpDrawer: 'Help',
}

export default en
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make a class for translation,

```
import ReactNative from "react-native";
import I18n from "react-native-i18n";
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";
import { SafeAreaView, AsyncStorage, NetInfo, Alert } from "react-native";

import en from "./en.json"; // JSON file of words in English
import lv from "./lv.json"; // JSON file of words in Your language

I18n.fallbacks = true;

I18n.translations = {
  en,
  lv
};

global.selectedLanguage = "";

AsyncStorage.getItem("SELECTED_LANGUAGE").then(value => {
  if (value) {
    let languageDict = JSON.parse(value);
    let language = languageDict.language;
    global.selectedLanguage = language;

    if (language === "English") {
      I18n.locale = "en";
    } else {
      I18n.locale = "lv";
    }
  } else {
    I18n.locale = "en";
  }
});

export function changeLanguage() {
  return (I18n.locale = "lv");
}

export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return I18n.t(name, params);
}

export default I18n;
```

Second, Use this in your UI conponents,

eg:

```
....
import { strings } from "../../i18n;
....

....
<Text style={styles.titleText}>{strings("sign_up")}</Text>
....
```

The key 'sign_up' will show you the selected language.

And when you switch the language update the async storage.

eg:

```
let dict = {
      language: this.state.selectedLanguage
    };
    AsyncStorage.setItem("SELECTED_LANGUAGE", JSON.stringify(dict));
```

Comment: how to get translations from webservice fro  my server?

Comment: If you have API, then first call that API, and use that in separate variables. 
let en = .. // json data from your server
let lv = .. // jsondata from your server
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  lv
};

Comment: can you Explain how to do it?

Comment: While your app is open, first call your API,(I think you know how to call API). Then the response will the JSON data, that will keep in a location (in a variable or state). Then use that variable or state in the above code. If you are stuck please feel free to ask the exact doubt.

Comment: i will ask further if i need help.